# What are the advantages of setting 'nativeQuery' to 'true' when using @Query?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

The documentation of Spring Data [mentions the `nativeQuery` property of the `@Query` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query), but it fails to mention the advantages:

> The `@Query` annotation allows for running native queries by setting the `nativeQuery` flag to true, as shown in the following example:
>
> ```java
> public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
>
>  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL_ADDRESS = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
>  User findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);
> }
> ```

I could not find any documentation on when and why to do this. What is the advantage of using `nativeQuery = true`?

Comment: We use native query when Spring data can't do what RDBMS do

Comment: If you don't know what a native SQL query is, it might also be the case that you don't know what a JPA query is either.  You might want to read a good tutorial on JPA with Spring.

Comment: this question should be "what is the difference between a native and a jpa query?"

Comment: The advantage is you can use native sql queries, but there are few advantages using JPQL over the native queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a `@Query` annotation has a `nativeQuery = true` parameter, the query will not be parsed as `JPQL`. This could lead to better performance, but is dangerous when you've created queries with, for example, the `MySQL` dialect and try to execute them on a `MS SQL` server.